# Parse Error on line 2 LPSolve

Tags: parse-error, lpsolve

I am new to LpSolve and im trying to solve a problem but i keep getting parse error and cant get the answer right. I cant find my mistake. here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/wtzeDXVS

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem was that i cant multiply variables, so i replaced the k values with the ones in the end of my code.